# Variable value not being assigned to another variable in C

Tags: c, variables, cs50

I'm currently taking a class to learn C. I have gotten my code to set the value input by the user to num but when I try to assign another variable(placeHolder1) the value of num and return that new variable, I am given a bunch of random numbers. Not exactly sure why the new variable does not receive whats held by num. In my original post I left out a lot of the code because I didn't know if I was able to share it all. Yes this is a CS50 problem, no I am not asking for a solution to the problem set altogether just the specified issue with the variable. A lot of it is commented out because I was trying to find out why I was getting a different value than expecting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

string cardType;
long get_card_num(string prompt);
long length;
long tempNumL;
long tempNumS;
int startNum;
long sum1;
long sum2;


int main(void)
{
        long n = get_card_num("Number: ");      //prompts user for input
        printf("%li\n",n);
}

long checksum(num)
{
    long placeHolderA=num;
    long placeHolderB=num/10;

    /*do
    {
        sum1+=(placeHolder1%10);
        placeHolder1=placeHolder1/100;
    }
    while(placeHolder1/100>1);

    do
    {
        sum2+=(placeHolder2%10);
        placeHolder2= placeHolder2/100;
    }
    while(placeHolder1/100>0);
    */
    return num;
}

long get_card_num(string prompt)
{
    long num;

            num = get_long("%s", prompt);           //assigns num to the value of what user input

        tempNumL=num; // used to get length
        tempNumS=num; // used to get starting num

    do
    {
        tempNumL = tempNumL/10;                 //gets length
        length++;
    }
    while(tempNumL>0);

    if(length<13)
    {
        get_card_num(prompt);
    }


    checksum(num);




    /*
    if((length==13 || length==16) && startNum==4)
    {
    }

    if(length==15)
    {
    }

    if(length==16 && startNum!=4)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID");
    }
*/
return num;
}
```

Comment: Where is `placeHolder1` defined in `get_num`? That can't be your actual code and if it is it can't possibly compile.

Comment: What's `long checksum(num)`? What do you expect of it?

Comment: Does this code actually compile? If not, please update with a full reproducible example.

Comment: is this a cs50 question?

Comment: I updated the question @M.M

Comment: @SteveFriedl I put the rest of the code

Comment: @RohanBari its updated

Comment: @kaylum it's updated

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're having difficulty with a concept called *variable scope.*

In this code

```
long checksum(num)
{
    long placeHolder1 = num;
}
```

`placeHolder1` will only exist during the function's execution.  Once execution leaves this function, placeHolder1 will go out of scope and effectively disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long checksum(long num) // it's in top because it's used after its declaration
{
    return num;
}

long get_num(char prompt[]) // 'string' is a concept of C++
{
    long num;

    printf("%s", prompt);
    scanf("%ld", &num); // assigns num to the value of what user input
                        // use %ld for 'long int'

    long placeHolder1 = checksum(num); // placeHolder1 wasn't declared here

    return placeHolder1;
}

int main(void)
{
    long n = get_num("Number: "); // prompts user for input
    printf("%ld\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Note:** The mistakes are commented just after the working code.

[Read about Variable Scopes in brief](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm) to know when and how should we declare the functions and variables when needed.

After correcting the silly errors, you'll get rid of incorrect output:

```
Number: 12
12
```

Also, there's no meaning of this: `long checksum(num)` declaration. You're taking the `num` which is unknown to the function as per of the rule of variable scope + if it's a `struct` or a data type, it must have a variable name.